# Generating Sequence for Each Group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sequence

How to generate this sequence for MySQL?
**(N.B. :- for each unique pair the sequence is generated afresh)**

1,1 -- 1
1,1 -- 2
1,1 -- 3
1,2 -- 1
1,2 -- 2
1,3 -- 1
1,4 -- 1
1,4 -- 2
1,4 -- 3

Comment: not clear to me what you need ? for generating sequences better to write a function rather than using DB

Comment: Technically, you also need PK before you begin.

Comment: Tables are already present.Two tables Category and SubCategory have two columns category_id and subcategory_id respectively. There is a 3rd table Specification. Now for each item (Cat + Subcat) there are multiple specifications. Now say for item 1 having category_id 1 and subcategory_id 1 there are 3 specifications. for item 2 there are 2, for 3 there is 1 and for 4 there are 3. In a single query I need to generate this sequence.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `row_number` function in SQL Server for MySQL

```
SELECT
  @row_number := CASE
    WHEN @conc_no = conc THEN
    @row_number + 1
    ELSE
    1
    END AS num,
  @conc_no := mydata.conc AS conc
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(num1, ",", num2) AS conc
    FROM
      table1
    ORDER BY
      num1 ASC, num2 ASC
    ) mydata
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad4a0/3/0

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much.But what if there are more columns? Say three or four? Will that work as good?

Comment: @TanmoyGhosh Just `CONCAT` all the columns you need with some special punctuations. Ensure the result string is unique for every group and that's ok.

Comment: @TanmoyGhosh I meant "accepting" my answer by clicking the check mark to the left of my answer, man. So that I can gain reputation (๑´ㅂ`๑)♡*

Answer (score 1):

create a table:-

```
create table dummy(id varchar(100));
```

insert values in a table :-

```
insert into dummy (id) values('1,1');    
insert into dummy (id) values('1,1');    
insert into dummy (id) values('1,1');    
insert into dummy (id) values('1,2');    
insert into dummy (id) values('1,2');    
insert into dummy (id) values('1,3');    
insert into dummy (id) values('1,4');    
insert into dummy (id) values('1,4');    
insert into dummy (id) values('1,4');
```

run the below query:-

```
select id,@aaaa:=ifnull(seq,@aaaa:=@aaaa+1)as seq from(select y.id,b,seq from (select 
id,@aaa:=@aaa+1 as b from dummy cross join (select @aaa:=0)a) as y  left join 
(select id,a,@aa:=@aa as seq from  (select * from (select id,@a:=@a+1 as a from dummy 
cross join (select @a:=0)a)as b group by id)a cross join (select @aa:=1)as d )
 as x on x.a=y.b) as z cross join  (select @aaaa:=0)a;
```